# Investing in index funds in Cyprus?

Tags: investing, index-fund, european-union, vanguard

I'm currently based in Cyprus and wanted to invest euros into the world's stock markets via index funds with low expense ratios. Research thus far into retail investing options here isn't promising.

Countries like the USA have brokerage firms such as Vanguard, Fidelity, Schwab, etc. that allow one to open an account, link your bank, and immediately purchase shares of funds with no additional management fees beyond the fees inherent in each fund.

Has anyone here managed to passively invest while in Cyprus? I wonder if it's possible to do so via brokerages in another EU-member state that has access to Vanguard funds (or similar)?

[A search brought me to this related question but no viable answer within: [Is it worth investing in Index Fund, Bond Index Fund and Gold at the same time?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/4593/is-it-worth-investing-in-index-fund-bond-index-fund-and-gold-at-the-same-time/86795#86795])

Comment: So, no answer? Nothing? after 2 years?